# How can I add a participant to an Issue through the GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm looking for a way to add a list of participants to a GitHub Issue using the GitHub API.

I have tried:

1. Assigning the issue through the GitHub API.

   - Works, adding participants, but may be too direct, and there is a limit of 10 assignees.
2. @mentioning users in the description and a comment.

   - Does not add participants

*My end goal here is to create an issue representing an deploy and @mention everyone who has a PR being deployed so that they know to help test.  I'd like everyone to get a GitHub notification about the issue as it is created.  Adding them to the list of participants seems like it should be the best way to accomplish this.*

Comment: any chance you figured this out? :)

Comment: Nope, I went with the @mention in the comment, but alas I don't think it added participants.

Comment: You can mention the people involved in the Issue/PR and instruct them that there's a "watch thread" button right at the bottom the page.